# Why does my Django view return a download of a file path instead of the actual file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, pdf

I am making a website that takes a user's file, translates the text in the file and returns it when they click the download button. However my website is returning an HTML file containing the file path instead of the actual file. I tried changing the response to a FileResponse but the result didn't change. I am using Django as the backend. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="download-btn" class="upload" type="submit" name="download_file">
    <svg width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11.5" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M19 9h-4V3H9v6H5l7 7 7-7zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z" fill="grey" />
    </svg>
    <a id="response_text_anchor" href="" download><p id="response_text"></p></a>            
</button>
```

JS:

```
xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log("Ready state: ", xhr.readyState);
            console.log("Status: ", xhr.status);
        
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    loaderDiv.style.display = 'none';
        
                    const downloadArrowDiv = document.querySelector('#download-btn');
                    downloadArrowDiv.style.display = 'flex';
        
                    const responseTextAnchor = document.querySelector('#response_text_anchor');
                    responseTextAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // Set href to the translated file link
        
                    const responseText = document.querySelector('#response_text');
                    responseText.textContent = 'Click to download';
        
                    // File was successfully translated, you can update UI here
                } else {
                    // Handle error case
                    console.error('Error translating file');
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
```

views.py:

The user uploads a file and clicks submit. When they do translateFile runs. After the file is translated they can click a download button containing an  which is supposed to download a pdf of their file. Instead the file path is returned.

```
def translateFile(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        source_language = request.POST.get('source_language')
        target_language = request.POST.get('target_language')


        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
            
            file = (converter(uploaded_file_path, source_language, target_language))#translates file
            file_location = uploaded_file_path
            #with open(file_location, 'rb') as f:
                #file_data = f.read()
            
            #response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/pdf')
            #response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
            #return response
            return HttpResponse(file_location)
    
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'translator_upload/upload.html')

@csrf_protect
def downloadFile(request):#request is file_location
    if request.method =='POST':
        file_location = request
        with open(file_location, 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()
        response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
        return response
```

Why does the file not download? Instead it returns an html file containing the path to the file instead.